# Struct array in struct [Objective-c]

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, arrays, struct

Let say I have these:

```
typedef id Title;

typedef struct{
    Title title;
    int pages;
}Book;
```

So far, the code is okay. But the problem is here:

```
typedef struct{
   int shelfNumber;
   Book book;   //How can I make this an array of Book?
}Shelf;
```

Like what I have stated in the comment in the code, I want to make Book as array so that it can hold a number of books. Is that even possible? If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef struct{
    int shelfNumber;
    Book book[10];   // Fixed number of book: 10
 }Shelf;
```

or

```
typedef struct{
    int shelfNumber;
    Book *book;     // Variable number of book
 }Shelf;
```

in the latter case you'll have to use `malloc` to allocate the array.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for. So I'm going to use pointer because I need the size to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could use [a flexible array member](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_42.html) to achieve this effect:

```
typedef struct {
    int shelfNumber;
    size_t nbooks;
    Book book[];
} Shelf;
```

This is an elegant use case because you have the simplicity of use of a static array but if you need to allocate a `Shelf` object of size `sz`, you only have to do one `malloc`:

```
Shelf *mkShelf(int num, size_t sz) {
    Shelf *s = malloc(sizeof(Shelf) + sz * sizeof(Book));
    if (!s) return NULL;
    *s = (Shelf){ num, sz };
    return s;
}
```

Compound literals and flexible array members that I used above are C99 features, so if you program with VC++ it might not be available.